# How to add rate limit in Ocelot using Ocelot Sql Server provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

```
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/weatherforecast",
  "DownstreamScheme": "https",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 7220
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/GatewayAPI",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
    "Get"
  ],
  "RateLimitOptions": {
    "ClientWhitelist": [],
    "EnableRateLimiting": true,
    "Period": "15s",
    "PeriodTimespan": 1,
    "Limit": 1
  }
}
```

In my SQL Database OcelotRoutes table Route column's data. I try Ocelot Sql Server provider  instead of JSON configuration.

```
builder.Services.AddOcelot()
    .AddSqlServerProvider(options =>
    {
        options.DbConnectionStrings = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection");
        options.MigrationsAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
    })
  .AddPolly();

await app.UseOcelotWithSqlServerProvider();
```

This is my program.cs file.

I try in Ocelot JSON configuration. It's Work fine. But Used to try in Ocelot SQL Server Provider. I can't get "rate limit exception message". I'm checking that in postman.

Comment: Have you tried GlobalConfiguration follow this document?https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/ratelimiting.html

Comment: @RuikaiFeng NO, {
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/weatherforecast",
  "DownstreamScheme": "https",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 7172
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gatewaycheck",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
    "Get"
  ],
  "RateLimitOptions": {
    "ClientWhitelist": [],
    "EnableRateLimiting": true,
    "Period": "20s",
    "PeriodTimespan": 1,
    "Limit": 1
  }
}    How to add

Comment: I Find my Answer "MY TYPO Mistake"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find my Answer "MY TYPO Mistake"

Comment: Please, clarify where was the typo

Comment: @GeorgeKarlinzer this one is correct format '"RateLimitOptions": {
    "ClientWhitelist": [],
    "EnableRateLimiting": true,
    "Period": "15s",
    "PeriodTimespan": 1,
    "Limit": 1
  }'
Instead of RateLimitOptions I code RateLimitRule.So, That's my mistake.